# Why do I get these syntax errors when I modify my .bash_profile in order to install Tensorflow + OpenCV on macOS Catalina?

Tags: bash, macos, tensorflow, terminal, anaconda

I am trying to create a deep learning environment on Jupyter Notebook (Python 3.7, macOS Catalina) and put Tensorflow and OpenCV on it. I am following the instructions on the following website: https://mc.ai/deep-learning-on-macos-catalina/ . I am at the step "Add following to .bash_profile file...". I just did (not sure when I was meant to add the part from "export PS1" to "/virtualenvwrapper.sh" so I just put it there rather arbitrarily) and it looks like this (after I take a look at it using nano .bash_profile).

```
export PS1="___________________    | \w @ \h (\u) \n| => "
export PS2="| =>
# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

However, I get two errors :

```
-bash: .bash_profile: line 16: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: .bash_profile: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What do I need to do to solve these in order to move on to the next step?

Otherwise, are there any more simple ways to use BOTH Tensorflow and OpenCV together in the same environment without having to go through all this? (knowing that I already have Anaconda Python 3.7)

Thanks a lot !

UPDATE : I tried things here and there, and my new .bash_profile looks like this now:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

export PS1="___________________    | \w @ \h (\u) \n| => "
export PS2="| =>

alias ll='ls -FGlAhp'

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

 >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

However I have a problem with the Terminal window now and I don't know how to deal with it.

I have the same errors practically :

```
-bash: .bash_profile: line 19: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: .bash_profile: line 24: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was supposed to add the following lines of code to my .bash_profile :                      # virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Comment: You didn't close double quote in 4-th line.

Comment: Thank you @Cromax, but why does the error refer to line 19?

Comment: Because, if you analyze it carefully, you will see, that not closed quote is, well, actually closed, but on line 12, then goes subshell expression, then again you reopen double quote, then you close it in line 14, then goes `$___conda_setup`, then you reopen double quote few times again and finally you open double quote at line 19. (after `...$PATH`) and never close it, so EOF is reached. Well, at this time line 19 is not a culprit, but side effect.

Comment: Oh okay I got it! Thanks a lot @Cromax

Comment: I guess you would spot the error much faster if you would use a text editor with syntax highlight. It would show you most part of the script highlighted as string, not as regular commands. 8) Have a nice day!

Comment: yes I will think about that! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cromax specified in the comment under my question post, I had forgotten to close the double quote in the 4th line.